# Rundeck error when job is running with success

Tags: windows, ssis, psexec, system-administration, rundeck

I have a job defined on Rundeck with a step that has a remote command. This command calls PSExec that calls a .cmd that executes DTSXExec.

After I running the job, I got an error on Rundeck. Altough, the DTSXExec runs smoothly.

Here is the log:

```
PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
14:39:11    Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
14:39:11    Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
14:39:11    
14:39:11    
14:39:11    C:\Windows\system32>D:
14:39:11    
14:39:11    D:\>cd D:\DTEXEC 
14:39:11    
14:39:11    D:\DTEXEC\DTSXExec.exe 32 CAR_ESTRUTURA_HIER 
14:39:25    
14:39:25    25-02-2019 14:39:10 - >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> BEGIN LOG <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
14:39:25    
14:39:25    25-02-2019 14:39:10 - CAR_ESTRUTURA_HIER - CAR_ESTRUTURA_HIER 32 bits execution.
14:39:25        
14:39:25    25-02-2019 14:39:25 - Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
14:39:25    Version 11.0.7001.0 for 32-bit
14:39:25    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
14:39:25    
14:39:25    DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_SUCCESS (0).
14:39:25    Started:  14:39:10
14:39:25    Finished: 14:39:25
14:39:25    Elapsed:  14.867 seconds
14:39:25    
14:39:25    
14:39:25    25-02-2019 14:39:25 - RETURN CODE: 0. 
14:39:25    
14:39:25    25-02-2019 14:39:25 - RETURN CODE: 0. No errors.
14:39:25    
14:39:25    25-02-2019 14:39:25 - >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> END LOG <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
14:39:25    
14:39:25    Connecting to localhost...
14:39:25    Starting PSEXESVC service on localhost...
14:39:25    Connecting with PsExec service on localhost...
14:39:25    Starting D:\teste3.cmd on localhost...
14:39:25    D:\teste3.cmd exited on localhost with error code 0.
14:39:25    Execution finished with the following error:
14:39:25    Failed: NonZeroResultCode: [WinRMPython] Result code: 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the service.log file (usually on /var/log/rundeck/service.log) for more clues. But in most cases that error is because exists a conflict with python libraries on your operating system (usually urllib3 or pywinrm), you can see your Python libs executing 'pip list' and install with 'pip install '.

Check that:

https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/py-winrm-plugin/issues/6

And that for PIP reference:

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/